# Apache redirect/rewrite of https hostname to https full URL

Tags: apache, redirect, https, url-rewriting

An Apache rewrite has been put in place to redirect the URL from http to https which works fine

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

However `https://hostname` goes to the 'itworks!'page

What would be the syntax to redirect `https://hostname` to `https://hostname/sub1/sub2`

Thanks

Comment: Tried many different options but for some reason could not rewrite the URL in https mode. In the end, I put a http redirect on the itworks! page, not the most elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Place this after the rules you have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ /sub1/sub2 [L]
```

If you want the actual URL in the browser's address bar to change to `/sub1/sub2`, then change the brackets from `[L]` to `[R=301,L]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it didn't seem to work tho. Tried a few variations of your code and each time it doesn't switch.